# Is there a way to tell Prolog that the argument X of a specific predicate f(X) is always true if the predicate is true?

Tags: prolog

Apologies if this is a silly question, but I haven't been able to find an answer.
Suppose I have some predicate, `proven_true(X)`, where `X` is some sort of factual statement like `person(bob)`. Is there any way to tell Prolog that if `proven_true(X)` is true, then `X` itself is also true? Say I define `proven_true(X)` as

```
proven_true(X) :- condition_1(X), condition_2(X) ... condition_n(X).
```

and in my facts, all of the above conditions are true for `X = person(bob)`. Then I not only want `proven_true(person(bob))` to be true, but also `person(bob)` to be true.

Obviously for a specific `X` this would be doable, but I couldn't get it to work for variable `X`. My first try was something along the lines of

```
X :- f(x).
```

but that didn't work because I was treating the head of the rule itself as a variable.
Thanks in advance for any assistance!

**Edit:**
To clear up some confusion, suppose my code was:

```
proven_true(X) :- condition_1(X), condition_2(X).
condition_1(dog(fido)).
condition_2(dog(fido)).
```

Then I could query `proven_true(dog(X))` and get `fido`, but if I queried `dog(X)`, I wouldn't get a result. So if I then wanted to use the fact that fido is a dog as a condition for another rule, I'd have to wrap it in the `proven_true()` predicate, e.g.:

```
barks(X) :- proven_true(dog(X)).
```

What I would like is some way to have `X` always be true if `proven_true(X)` is also true. That way, I could write the above rule as

```
barks(X) :- dog(X).
```

For a specific term like `dog(X)`, I could achieve this using

```
dog(X) :- proven_true(dog(X)).
```

but I'd like to be able to achieve it for all terms. Something like

```
X :- proven_true(X).
```

(although this doesn't work). Hopefully that clears up confusion.

Comment: Also asked at https://www.reddit.com/r/prolog/comments/zqf30v/setting_a_term_x_true_if_it_is_an_argument_of_a/

Comment: be more specific please. that is, edit your post to show an REPL interaction that you would like to have. as an example, I could imagine an interaction like `?- car(X).` and the reply `X = tesla.`. what do _you_ have in mind?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, I've updated the post to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You want `asserta/1` or `assertz/1`. It will modify the Prolog database during run-time.

```
proven_true(X) :- condition_1(X), condition_2(X), assertz(X).
condition_1(dog(fido)).
condition_2(dog(fido)).
```

`assertz` adds the assertion at the end of the database.